# JQuery isotope with Swipe plugins - problems reload elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe, jquery-isotope, masonry

I am using the jQuery Isotope and Swipe plugin for a Photo gallery. I want to reload all the items when i close the gallery Swipe but there is a problem. All the items aren't reload very well and when i try to select a new category of items, they just split far from the others. I try lot of things like isotope('reloadItems'),  isotope('reLayout') but without success.
I don't know where the problem come.
This pages will show you what i mean : http://digitale-photographie.fr/portfolio.php

Also, code samples:

**portfolio.php**

```
        <div id="sort">
            <a href="#" class="selected" data-filter="*">Tous</a>
            <a href="#" data-filter=".Soirée">Soirée</a>
            <a href="#" data-filter=".Mariage">Mariage</a>
            <a href="#" data-filter=".Portrait">Portrait</a>
            <a href="#" data-filter=".Grossesse">Grossesse</a>
            <a href="#" data-filter=".Publicité">Publicité</a>
            <a href="#" data-filter=".Industrielle">Industrie</a>
        </div>
        <div id="photogrid">
            <?php               
                for ($j=0;$j<=$i-1;$j++)
                {
                    $image_mini = '<img src="photos/portfolio/thumbnails/'.$tab_image_mini[$j].'" />';
                    echo '<div class="thumbnail '.$tab_class[$j].'" data-background="photo.image.large"><a class="thumb">'.$image_mini.'</a></div>';      
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="mainimage">
            <div id='photos' class='swipe'>
                <div class='swipe-wrap'>
                <?php       
                    for ($j=0;$j<=$i-1;$j++)
                    {
                    echo '<div class="img '.$tab_class[$j].'" data-image="photos/portfolio/zoom/'.$tab_image_zoom[$j].'" data-width="1024" data-height="702">
                            <div class="ui photoinfo hidden">
                                <!-- Photo Title & Description -->
                                <h2 class="phototitle">Runaway...</h2>
                                <!-- Metadata -->
                                <ul class="metadata"></ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>';      
                    }
                ?>
                </div>  
            </div>                      
            <div class="ui button backbutton hidden">
                <div class="chevron">
                    <div class="upper"></div>
                    <div class="lower"></div>
                </div>
                <p>Retourner à la galerie</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ui photonav button prev hidden">
                <div class="chevron">
                    <div class="upper"></div>
                    <div class="lower"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui photonav button next hidden">
                <div class="chevron">
                    <div class="upper"></div>
                    <div class="lower"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**js code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).load(function(){ 
    var $container = $('#photogrid');
    $container.isotope({ 
        filter: '*', 
        animationOptions: { 
            duration: 750, 
            easing: 'linear', 
            queue: false, 
        } 
    }); 

    $('#sort a').click(function(){ 
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter'); 
        /*$('.img').isotope({
            filter: selector, 
            animationOptions: { 
                duration: 750, 
                easing: 'linear', 
                queue: false, 
            }           
        });*/
        $container.isotope({ 
            filter: selector, 
            animationOptions: { 
                duration: 750, 
                easing: 'linear', 
                queue: false, 
            } 
        }); 
        return false; 
    });   
});

// hide photo view with back button
$('.backbutton').click(function() {
    // Hide photo layer and current photo
    mainimageElement.removeClass('visible black');
    $('.ui').addClass('hidden');
    if (isTouchDevice()) {
        headerElement.removeClass('hidden');
    }

    $('#photogrid').isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope();

    mainimageElement.removeAttr('style');
    thumbnailElements.removeAttr('style');
    sortElement.removeAttr('style');
    headerElement.removeClass('opaque');
    setHeaderOpacity();

    // put selected thumbnail back in its place
    retractThumbnail(selectedThumbnail);
    retractThumbnail(selectedSort);

    setTimeout(function() {
        // animate in other thumbnails
        var delay = 0;      
        thumbnailElements.each(function() {
            delay = delay + 10;
            var $this = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $this.removeClass('background');
            }, delay);
        });
    }, 1)

});
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Clicking on the link gives "404 Not Found" - please check it's correct.

Comment: as i start i'd use anyway isotope v2 http://isotope.metafizzy.co/